# Infinite series defines meromorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I am not sure if this is true, but I am trying to prove that the following series defines a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}^*$:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{q^kz}{(q^kz-1)^2},$$

where $|q|>1$.

I don't really know how to go about proving this so I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\left|\frac{q^kz}{(q^kz-1)^2}\right|=\left|\frac z{q^k\left(z-q^{-k}\right)^2}\right|\implies$$

$$\left|\frac z{q^{k+1}(z-q^{-{(k+)1}})^2}\right|\left|\frac{q^k(z-q^{-k})^2}{z}\right|=\frac1{|q|}\frac{|z-q^{-k}|}{|z-q^{-(k+1)}|}\xrightarrow [k\to\infty]{}\frac1{|q|}<1$$

Comment: I don't see how this hint can help!

Comment: Ratio test for **any** $\;z\in\Bbb Z\;$ rings a bell...? The principal of the series is the singular bit, and the rest defines a holomorphic function.